# Accessing of interface methods

Tags: c#

Actually the code below is Simple example of interface.But it showing an error  'PublicDemo.DemoPublic' does not implement interface member 'PublicDemo.demo1.two()'. 'PublicDemo.DemoPublic.two()' cannot implement an interface member because it is not public.

```
namespace PublicDemo
{
public interface demo
{
    void Demo();
}
public interface demo1:demo
{
    void one();
    void two();
}


class DemoPublic :demo1
{
    protected internal string variable;

   public void Demo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", variable);

    }
    public void one()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is one method");
    }
    protected void two()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is two method");
    }


}


class Excute : DemoPublic
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Excute Dp = new Excute();
        Dp.variable = Console.ReadLine();
        Dp.Demo();
        Dp.one();
        Dp.two();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
}
```

i need why it is not working

Comment: Why is it protected Void Two()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means what is says. Your two method is protected.  It needs to be public if implemented from an interface.

> protected void two(){
>
> ```
>     Console.WriteLine("this is two method");
> }
> ```

change it to public

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
protected void two()
{
    Console.WriteLine("this is two method");
}
```

into

```
public void two()
{
    Console.WriteLine("this is two method");
}
```

Comment: @Kireet, interface is a contract that means all implementations have to agree to implement public methods

Comment: one more doubt .is it possible to declare interface as protected

Comment: Yes, you can modify accessibility of interface itself, but not of its members. You can work around this using explicit interface implementation.

Comment: @Kireet If it is the nested interface you can make it protected, otherwise not.

Comment: can you give a simple example of multiple interfaces

Comment: Interfaces are meant to be used by code that doesn't care about the actual implementation. Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b5b8ezk(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You yourself answered the question:

> 'PublicDemo.DemoPublic.two()' cannot implement an interface member because it is not public.

Answer is Interface members have to be public.

Answer (score 0):

Change Protected to Public.You have defined an public Interface.Once you define Public Interface,the Contracts in the Interface also will be public by Default.

```
public void two()
{
    Console.WriteLine("this is two method");
}
```